# download files and showing process like google play

Tags: android, google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: show notification bar on downloading application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135389/android-show-notification-bar-on-downloading-application)

I want to make my android app that can download file like google play.

I have few questions, so thankful anyone can help me,
google use notification to update status bar(like downloading..) and process download file updated via expanded view in the customize notification or they created a process bar which can show when downloading file and hide when complete in main layout? Which is right?

but Expanding/Collapsing notification view only available in Android 4.1 and later. 
How can they do it?

Answer (score 2):

Basically what Google play uses for its download is the API DownloadManager. It handles the notification bar itself, so you need not worry about it. When download is completed, it will cancel the notification and you will be notified that it is complete.

If you do not want to use it, then you may have to write your own download manager and handle everything yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Google use DownloadManager for download file.But how way google show process download files? I see google doesn't use process bar in the notification expanded view?

Comment: DownloadManager handles showing progress of download in the notification bar.

Comment: You mean download manager handles showing progress of download in the notification bar (like downloading..) and the percentage of download file with process bar ?

Comment: Exactly! It handles everything :)